# unexpected token } in JSON at position 351 while parsing near '..."license": "ISC",

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I'm new to JavaScript and JSON and I'm trying to upload my NPM package. For some reason, I get this error when I try to publish it:

```
Unexpected token } in JSON at position 351 while parsing near '..."license": "ISC",

},
"bugs": {
"e..."
```

Here's my JSON file.

```
{
"name": "M-P-Formulas-JS",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "The M-P-Formulas package for JavaScript. This package allows the user to use math and physics formulas such as the Pythagorean Theorem.",
"main": "mpformulasJS.js",
"author": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com",
    "name": "Jeff Lockhart",
    "url": "",
    "license": "ISC",
},
"bugs": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com",
},
"dependencies": {
    "Math": "",
},
"keywords": [
    "mpformulas",
    "mpformulasjs",
    "m-p-formulas-js",
    "math",
    "physics",
    "formulas",
    "module",
    "package",
 ],
}
```

I even ran `npm cache clean` but, since it did not work, I can assure that my code is wrong. If so, how can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the trailing comma after the keywords array. Remove every trailing comma

Comment: What code is wrong? Where is your code?

Comment: JSON does not allow trailing commas after the last element of an array.

Comment: Actually, remove the trailing comma after each last line one an object or array. I can see at least 5.

Comment: *All* the stray trailing commas are syntax errors in JSON.

Comment: If your IDE does not support JSON you can try an online tool like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: trailing commas are not allowed in json

Comment: @JeffLockhart Try my answer for dynamically remove that kind of  commas :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the extra comma because it's the last item before closing the object. It results in an invalid JSON.

`"license": "ISC", // <--- Remove this comma`

```
"bugs": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com", // <--- Remove this comma
}
```

JS objects and JSON are different. For instance, this is a valid JS object, but invalid JSON :

```
bugs : {
    email : "8b21espq@gmail.com",
}
```

Valid JSON would be :

```
"bugs": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, please consider validating / upvoting the answer if it was useful.

Comment: `"package",` is missing :p

Comment: you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the commas preceeding the closing braces and brackets. Use a comma only to separate elements. The last element should not have a trailing comma. Some parsers will let you get away with this but it's invalid JavaScript and JSON.

[Here a tool for testing JSON formatting.](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
{
"name": "M-P-Formulas-JS",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "The M-P-Formulas package for JavaScript. This package allows the user to use math and physics formulas such as the Pythagorean Theorem.",
"main": "mpformulasJS.js",
"author": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com",
    "name": "Jeff Lockhart",
    "url": "",
    "license": "ISC",              <-- Lose the comma.
},
"bugs": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com", <-- Lose the comma.
},
"dependencies": {
    "Math": "",                    <-- Lose the comma.
},
"keywords": [
    "mpformulas",
    "mpformulasjs",
    "m-p-formulas-js",
    "math",
    "physics",
    "formulas",
    "module",
    "package",                     <-- Lose the comma.
 ],                                <-- Lose the comma.
}
```

Comment: Not valid in JSON, but trailing commas have been valid in Javascript for some time.

Comment: @jonathan.ihm is correct. My bad. Commas are not currently allowed in JSON but have always been allowed in Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Comment: Thanks for adding the reference link, I didn't get a chance to :-) I just wanted to clarify that since trailing commas are actually preferred in some cases!

Answer (score 0):

> Your JSON have unwanted `,` in end of the objects. So please try this below code to remove the `,` after the last item of every objects.

```js
var xx={
"name": "M-P-Formulas-JS",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "The M-P-Formulas package for JavaScript. This package allows the user to use math and physics formulas such as the Pythagorean Theorem.",
"main": "mpformulasJS.js",
"author": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com",
    "name": "Jeff Lockhart",
    "url": "",
    "license": "ISC",
},
"bugs": {
    "email": "8b21espq@gmail.com",
},
"dependencies": {
    "Math": "",
},
"keywords": [
    "mpformulas",
    "mpformulasjs",
    "m-p-formulas-js",
    "math",
    "physics",
    "formulas",
    "module",
    "package",
 ],
}

var xxx=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx).replace('",]','"]').replace('",}','"}'));
console.log(xxx);
```